# Apache2 PassEnv not working after reboot

Tags: apache-2.2, environment-variables

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with a vanilla apache install. In my Apache Config, I'm using `PassEnv` to pass an environment variable:

```
PassEnv MY_VARIABLE
```

`MY_VARIABLE` is defined in `/etc/environment`:

```
MY_VARIABLE=true
```

If I stop and start apache, the variable is picked up and all is well. However, after reboot, apache does not pick up `MY_VARIABLE`.

Does Apache start before variables in `/etc/environment` are set? Is there some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

That is weird !
You can try a cheat by sourcing /etc/environment in /etc/init/d/httpd (not recommended on all occasions)

1) A straight forward solution will be a custom script to launch your apache with your own configuration , you can do all the housekeeping jobs in the script , please use -f to specify your custom httpd.conf file.

2) Alternative : use setEnv to set the required environment variable from httpd.conf itself.

3) Alternative , try to export the required variables from .bashrc.